# Getting the userinfo from specific sharepoint site using sharepoint web service

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-services, sharepoint-foundation

I am using /_vti_bin/usergroup.asmx service and getting the userinfo using GetAllUserCollectionFromWeb(). But i need to pass in the specific site and need to get the users info of that site alone. Which sharepoint service to use? How to get that?

Thanx in advance

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159646/getting-the-userinfo-from-specific-sharepoint-site-using-sharepoint-web-service

Answer (score 2):

I think that after creating the web service instance You should change the Url property to "http://YourSpecificSite/_vti_bin/usergroup.asmx" and then call the GetAllUserCollectionFromWeb() method.

```
wsUsersGroups.UserGroup _WSUsersGroups = new wsUsersGroups.UserGroup();
_WSUsersGroups.Url = "http://YourSpecificSite/_vti_bin/usergroup.asmx";
XmlNode ndUsers = _WSUsersGroups.GetAllUserCollectionFromWeb()
```

Comment: +1 just add the `/_vti_bin/usergroup.asmx` on the end of your site collection or sub site URL.